# Parsing malformed HTML with Mechanize (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'd like to process an HTTP response that has a lot of HTML in it but is not itself a valid HTML file.

I'm aware that I could use Nokogiri as follows:  `page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.body)`, however, I'd like to have access to the `Mechanize` methods like `Mechanize::Page.search`.  Is there any way to work with this HTML as a [Mechanize::Page](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html), or through some other Mechanize class?

Comment: Mechanize::Page.search -> this is actually handed off to a nokogiri method. You can use 'search' and 'at' with both Mechanize::Page and Nokogiri::HTMLDocument

Answer (score 2):

Actually, looks like I've found the answer to my own question:

```
 page  = Mechanize::Page.new(URI.parse('http://example.com'), {'content-type'=>'text/html'},(page.body), 200, agent)
```